# Conditionally $project from different fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the unfortunate problem of a data structure changing on me around six months ago. Therefore, I have a document that used to look like...

```
{
  fruits: [
    {
      id: 123
    },
    {
      id: 456
    }
  ]
}
```

(Important to note that the `id` is not the `ObjectId` BSON type, it's just a random series of characters generated by the client side).

...but now has the `id` key changed to.

```
{
  fruits: [
    {
      fruit_id: 'xxx'
    },
    {
      fruit_id: 'yyy'
    }
  ]
}
```

So, I'm trying to do a `$project` to have both `id` and `fruit_id` changed to something generic like `general_id`, so that I can continue with another aggregation like `$group` and just reference the one field

I've tried something along the lines of:

```
[
  $unwind: {
    path: '$fruits'
  },
  $project: {
    general_id: {
      $cond: {
        if: {
          'fruits.fruit_id': {
            $type: ['string']
          }
        },
        then: '$fruits.fruit_id',
        else: '$fruits.id'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you are after here, but for a general case of knowing **two** possibilities it's probably better to use [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) to return the value for the field if present, otherwise return the other field's value.

Adding a little more data for demonstration since you probably don't want to loose anything else in the array elements:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  fruits: [
    {
      id: 123,
      data: 1
    },
    {
      id: 456,
      data: 2
    }
  ]
},
{
  _id: 2,
  fruits: [
    {
      fruit_id: 'xxx',
      data: 1
    },
    {
      fruit_id: 'yyy',
      data: 2
    }
  ]
},
{
  _id: 3,
  fruits: [
    {
      fruit_id: 'xxx',
      data: 1,
    },
    {
      fruit_id: 'yyy',
      data: 2
    },
    {
      id: 123,
      data: 3
    },
    {
      id: 456,
      data: 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can either do the process using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) as the *first* step, which does make path naming easier and especially with [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) instead of [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#conditionally-exclude-fields):

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$fruits" },
  { "$addFields": {
    "fruits": {
      "id": "$$REMOVE",
      "fruit_id": "$$REMOVE",
      "general_id": { "$ifNull": [ "$fruits.id", "$fruits.fruit_id" ] }
    }
  }}
])
```

That uses [`$$REMOVE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#conditionally-exclude-fields) from MongoDB 3.6 and above ( which should be the minimal version you are using ) in order to "remove" the fields you don't want. You don't need to do that and can just declare everything you actually want with [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) if you don't have support.

Then of course has the alternate with an [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) expression.

This gives results on that data like:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "fruits" : { "data" : 1, "general_id" : 123 } }
{ "_id" : 1, "fruits" : { "data" : 2, "general_id" : 456 } }
{ "_id" : 2, "fruits" : { "data" : 1, "general_id" : "xxx" } }
{ "_id" : 2, "fruits" : { "data" : 2, "general_id" : "yyy" } }
{ "_id" : 3, "fruits" : { "data" : 1, "general_id" : "xxx" } }
{ "_id" : 3, "fruits" : { "data" : 2, "general_id" : "yyy" } }
{ "_id" : 3, "fruits" : { "data" : 3, "general_id" : 123 } }
{ "_id" : 3, "fruits" : { "data" : 4, "general_id" : 456 } }
```

If you wanted to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on that value, then there's no need for an intermediate "project" of any kind. Just do the [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) directly in that stage:

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$fruits" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "$ifNull": [ "$fruits.id", "$fruits.fruit_id" ] },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

And output:

```
{ "_id" : "yyy", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "xxx", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 456, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 123, "count" : 2 }
```

Or if you actually did not need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array for other purposes, you can use `$map` and some other manipulation with [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/):

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "fruits": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$fruits",
        "in": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            { "$arrayToObject": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$this" },
                "cond": { "$not": { "$in": [ "$$this.k", ["fruit_id","id"] ] } }
              }
            }},
            {
              "general_id": { "$ifNull": ["$$this.id","$$this.fruit_id"] }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Which returns results like:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "fruits" : [
                {
                        "data" : 1,
                        "general_id" : 123
                },
                {
                        "data" : 2,
                        "general_id" : 456
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "fruits" : [
                {
                        "data" : 1,
                        "general_id" : "xxx"
                },
                {
                        "data" : 2,
                        "general_id" : "yyy"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 3,
        "fruits" : [
                {
                        "data" : 1,
                        "general_id" : "xxx"
                },
                {
                        "data" : 2,
                        "general_id" : "yyy"
                },
                {
                        "data" : 3,
                        "general_id" : 123
                },
                {
                        "data" : 4,
                        "general_id" : 456
                }
        ]
}
```

Adding an [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) *after* that returns just the same as before. But the more complex operations are probably better suited to where you want to keep this as an array.

This time we removed the `id` and `fruit_id` by converting each array element into an array of "key/value" pairs via [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/). We then [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) the array based on those `"k"` values, which are the names of the fields. The [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) makes this an object again, with all other content except those fields.

The [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) is to [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) what [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) is to the root "document", in that it takes multiple objects and "merges" them together. Thus the "filtered" object as described before, and the new object with only the `general_id` key and it's value translated from whichever field was present.

### Lists of More than Two Fields

As a final note, [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) works better than [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) where you have just **two** values, but neither is actually that great if there is a larger possible list. You can nest [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) expressions or even use [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/), but really it's probably best to filter content out via the [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) as seen before:

```
var valid_names = [ "id", "fruit_id", "apple_id", "orange_id" ];

Model.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$fruits" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": { "$objectToArray": "$fruits" },
              "cond": { "$in": [ "$$this.k", valid_names ] }
            }
          },
          "in": "$$this.v"
        }},
        0
      ]
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}  
])
```

That usually makes the most sense, otherwise for working with such a list in dynamic way you end up building aggregation pipeline stages in code, such as with using [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) would be:

```
var valid_names = [ "id", "fruit_id", "apple_id", "orange_id" ];

var branches = valid_names.map(name => 
  ({
    "case": { "$gt": [`$fruits.${name}`, null ] },
    "then": `$fruits.${name}`
  })
)

Model.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$fruits" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "$switch": { branches, "default": null } },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

Which looks cleaner in your code, but actually sends a much larger pipeline in BSON:

```
[
    { "$unwind" : "$fruits" },
    { "$group" : {
      "_id" : {
        "$switch" : {
          "branches" : [
           { 
             "case" : { "$gt" : [ "$fruits.id", null ] },
             "then" : "$fruits.id"
           },
           {
             "case" : { "$gt" : [ "$fruits.fruit_id", null ] },
             "then" : "$fruits.fruit_id"
           },
           {
             "case" : { "$gt" : [ "$fruits.apple_id", null ] },
             "then" : "$fruits.apple_id"
           },
           {
             "case" : { "$gt" : [ "$fruits.orange_id", null ] },
             "then" : "$fruits.orange_id"
           }
         ],
         "default" : null
        }
      },
      "count" : { "$sum" : 1 }
    }}
]
```

Comment: This is a very comprehensive answer. Thanks for that.